# Solution Import: processtrigger With Id = [Guid] Does Not Exist

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

When trying to import a solution I get the following error:

> processtrigger With Id = [Guid] Does Not Exist

The import does not succeed. The same solution has previously been imported to the same environment without issues.

This might have started happening after installing [Update 0.2 for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3075889). I am thus running CRM 7.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until this issue has been fixed you can remove all references to business rules/workflows from the solution before attempting to import it. This will result in the import succeeding (though any changes to business rules/workflows will of course not be imported):

1. Edit *customizations.xml*
2. Remove all `<Workflow></Workflow>` element nodes (alternatively remove only the nodes related to the error).
3. Import the solution to the target environment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with importing entities with business rules after installing Update 0.2.

A temporary fix is to delete business rules from the target environment (every time) before importing.

It appears that Microsoft is working on a solution:

> [...] [product team is working on it and has decided to release the fix as
> part of Update 0.3.](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/180593?pi51685=2#responses)